# Fatal error with php client library

Tags: php, google-oauth, google-api-php-client, google-ads-api

> PHP Fatal error: Class 'Google\AdsApi\Common\OAuth2TokenBuilder' google api

What this error is all about?

I installed Google APIs PHP Client library using composer, but I got this error.

I tried running the GetCampaigns.php Example code. Please Explain. 
The code look like this:

```
 // Generate a refreshable OAuth2 credential for authentication.
    $oAuth2Credential = (new OAuth2TokenBuilder())
    ->fromFile()
    ->build();
```

Comment: Need help. Thanks

Comment: Provide is us more context, how does yoru code look that is causing this error? https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-php-lib/issues/205

Comment: @KrisRoofe I already tried to search google. They always said that need to follow the steps on installing the google api. I did it. But still got this. error. They dont even have steps on how to fix it.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: @BolambaoReymond thanks, but I still miss part of the code. Did you include vendor/autoload.php? Did you add the 'use' statement for the OAuth2TokenBuilder class before calling it?